# BeanCreationException Vaadin

Tags: gwt, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin4spring, beancreationexception

I'm trying to integrate Spring Boot Vaadin (https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring) with Vaadin's Dashboard Demo Code (https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo). The only thing modification I made was add the annotation "@VaadinUI" in the DashboardUI class. I checked in my code using the branch "integrate-vaadin-dashboard-demo-project".

I get the error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider.

I'm not really sure what the message means. Can somebody explain it and come up with a resolution to the error message?

Gist Error Output:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43d602c1105e00d4d7d6

Clone Url:
https://github.com/caritos/pangolin.git

Branch: 
integrate-vaadin-dashboard-demo-project

Answer (score 2):

You pack javax validation api 1.0 in your jar.  This is the version the GWT compiler needs (when you build a widgetset).  But spring-boot depends on version 1.1.  Usually the problem is the other way around...

Comment: I am using javax.valdation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final.

Comment: when `mvn package` the project and look into the jar, there is 1.0.0.